# XCode list of project configurations

Tags: xcode, configuration, build, terminal

I'm writing script that build apps with cron task, I can build any app with terminal call like
**xcodebuild [-project projectname] [-activetarget] [-alltargets] [-target targetname] [-parallelizeTargets] [-activeconfiguration] [-configuration configurationname] [-sdk  | ] [buildaction ...] [setting=value ...] [-default=value ...**

I can set '-configuration' value to Release (common for most of apps), but I'm confused when app does not have this configuration (so for example it has AdHoc or Distr, etc)

Is there any opportunity to retrieve list of configuration set for project so I can choose what I need and put it as -configuration value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to type

```
xcodebuild -list
```

it will show all targets, build configurations, and schemas.